# Every time I get to somewhere between 15 and 20 consecutive days it resets my counter, what should I do about it?

Tags: support, profile-page

Just now it says in my profile, "visited    94 days, 1 consecutive"

That can't possibly be right. I not only have visited the site for more then fifteen consecutive days, I've probably posted either question/answers/comments on all of those days. It says I wasn't on the site on Friday but I most definitely was.

What's the proper course of action for me to take?

Comment: Are you sure you're visiting every day? The site's day tracking is based on Greenwich Mean Time. You can log onto the site on separate days of your local time and actually miss the Greenwich clock.

Answer (score 5):

In the first instance the appropriate course of action is to attract the attention of a moderator (check). They would then tell you that a quick look at your "all actions" tab shows that you failed to check in to the site on the 25th June, the 21st June and between the 2nd and 8th of June.

This may (as @phantom42 has [pointed out](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7016/every-time-i-get-to-somewhere-between-15-and-20-consecutive-days-it-resets-my-co#comment17633_7016)) be due to the fact that the [site clock](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27199/what-is-an-se-day-when-does-each-day-start) is based on GMT. It's therefore possible that you checked in on those days locally, yet still managed to spend more than 24 hours off the site.

Assuming you're still unhappy, you can always email the [support team](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/contact) although I suspect their answer will be much the same as the one above.

Comment: When I look at my actions it only shows if I asked. answered, commented, or reviewed something. GMT midnight is 7pm my time. From Thursday 7pm till Friday 7pm I was definitely on the site. I had a 9pm meeting with a programmer. I was on before that. I ended up going out late, really late afterwards, came home, logged on for a minute, slept, then logged on again in the afternoon before  7pm for sure. I'm not saying I posted anything but I definitely looked at my account, read some stuff, & clicked on things on the site. Does that not count for being on the site or do you actually have to post?

Comment: @JMFB - Is it possible you weren't logged in? FYI, you don't need to be active, just present. http://meta.webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/376/whats-the-deal-with-the-enthusiast-badge